# Best practice -- how to get back the internal binding from controller factory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, dependency-injection, ninject

I am following "ASP.Net MVC 3" by Steven Sanderson and Adam Freeman, and at one point they define `ControllerFactory`. The exposed interface is for creating controllers, and what is injected into them (like classes providing data) is black box (for outside world).

I am at the point, that I don't really want to get any controller, but the binding set for controller -- namely class providing data.

I could add another method for controller factory (like `GetBinding`) and it would work, but would it be the *right* way to do it?

---

Just to focus on something. I have `IDataProvider` and two classes -- `MockupProvider` and `ProviderForReal`. I would like to set it once, that for now whenever I need `IDataProvider` I will get `MockupProvider`. This is set up (by me) in controller factory.

And I would like to retrieve what I set up in most *elegant* way, so I won't bind again interface-class again. Is adding such method -- `GetBinding` -- to controller factor a good pattern?

*I am not constructing the controller, I need binding controllers use.*

---

### In other words...

There is controller factory. Inside there are defined some bindings. I have to use retrieve them (binding, not controller). Technically I could do this in several ways:

- take a look at the code, look at specific binding, and use the the bound type (hardcoding it) somewhere else
- add public method to controller factory `GetBinding`
- ...?

What is the right way?

---

### Update

My controller factory:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninject_kernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninject_kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninject_kernel.Bind<IBookRepository>().To<DataManagement.Concrete.EFBookRepository>();
        // ninject_kernel.Bind<IBookRepository>().ToConstant(DataManagement.Mocks.Mocks.BookRepository);
    }

    public T GetBinding<T>()
    {
        return ninject_kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        else
            return (IController)ninject_kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your use-case. Is your intention to have bound MockupProvider in some testing configuration and ProviderForReal in some release configuration?

Comment: Testing/release config -- it does not matter. I re-use the binding in several places, so I would like to define `IA->FooA` once for entire solution, and whenever I need `IA` I would get `FooA` not because I hardcoded it, but because I configured it that way. Configure once -- use many (times). Since it is called `ControllerFactory` it does not seem right for me to get from such class just bindings.

Comment: Sry, but I still don't understand. Why can't you just use NinjectControllerFactory and let it do to work for you? Than you can simply register your IA->FooA in kernel and reuse it everywhere (depends on registration scope)

Comment: @mipe34, let's say you there is `IDataProvider` and 2 implementations (as above), could you please post code of the ControllerFactory you have in mind? In regular answer so I could accept it, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm trying to answer your questions following the comments. If it won't be suitable for you I'm prepared to delete it.*

So in my ASP.NET MVC applications I'm using ninject and its mvc extension to inject dependencies to my controllers (and underlying services and repositories).

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication
{
        /// this is here only to see that NinjectHttpApplication uses its own ControllerFactory, which is supposed to create your controllers with dependencies injected
        protected override Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory CreateControllerFactory()
        {
            return base.CreateControllerFactory();
        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            // here you can configure your bindings according to actual requirements 
            kernel.Bind<IDataProvider>().To<ProviderForReal>().InRequestScope(); 
            kernel.Bind<IDataService>().To<RealDataService().InRequestScope();                
            return kernel;
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataProvider dataService;
    // i will get injected an IDataProvider according to my actual configuration
    public MyController(IDataService dataService)
    {
          this.dataService = dataService;
    }
}
```

**IDataService**

```
public class RealDataService: IDataService{
     private readonly IDataProvider dataProvider;
     public RealDataService(IDataProvider dataProvider){
         this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
     } 
}
```

***Update***

You do not need to write your own controller factory. In the code above I have put my override of `CreateControllerFactory` method only to show that `Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication` implicitly overrides this method and uses its own `NinjectControllerFactory` implmentation which will resolve dependencies for you (even if that dependencies are indirect - as you can see in my updated code => Ninject will resolve it for you because it will see that `MyController` needs `IDataService` and will look into bindings and will see that there is binding to `RealDataService`, but it has only constructor with dependency on `IDataProvider`. So it will look again to bindings and will see that `IDataProvider` is bound to `ProviderForReal` than it will create `ProviderForReal` inject it to `ReadDataService` and than RealDataService to `MyController`).

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand fully the first part of the code, because you override method to call base one, so it has zero effect if I am not mistaken. But anyway, let's assume this is basic framework. Now -- I would like to get implementation of `IDataProvider` in some other class (not controller). How to get it? *Just for comparison I updated the question with my controller factory -- the question is about method GetBinding. Is this a right way to do it?*

Comment: See my update (I have also updated the code). *Just try it and you will see if that works ;-)*.

Comment: Thank you for your work however still there is no way to know what is the implementation of the interface for the "outside world" and my question is about it. In your version I presume it should be additional method in `MvcApplication` to get that binding (one of those two you defined). Now -- adding such method to `MvcApplication` is the best practice?

Comment: What do you mean by the "outside world"? As I have pointed out in my answer - Ninject will resolve the whole dependency tree for you? I thought you have an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: I checked the Ninject source. Ok, so you retrieve the Kernel from MvcApplication and from there you retrieve the binding, like IDataProvider --> ProviderForReal. Correct?

Comment: Yes. The method CreateKernel() is implementation of its abstract declaration in NinjectHttpApplication. As you can see here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/tree/2.2.0.0/mvc2/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc in NinjectHttpApplication the kernel is created at application_start and then when ControllerFactory is needed it will yields NinjectControllerFactory with kernel as input argument. Sorry that I didn't mentioned that I'm refering to Ninject 2.2 because there have been changes for this in later versions.